# Evaluating $\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu})=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Evaluating: $\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu})=0$

$=\eta_{\mu\nu}\ddot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu+\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\ddot{x}^\nu$

I understand that we can relabel $\mu$ and $\nu$ in the second term

$=\eta_{\mu\nu}\ddot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu+\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\nu\ddot{x}^\mu=2\eta_{\mu\nu}\ddot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu=0$
$\eta_{\mu\nu}\ddot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu=0$

Does this imply that $\ddot{x}^\mu$ and $\dot{x}^\nu$ commute? If so why?

Comment: $\ddot x^\mu$ and $\dot x^\nu$ are just ordinary real numbers. Real numbers commute.